# Use Arrayformula to auto-populate column in Google Sheets based on condition

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'll do my best to explain this. So, I want to use Arrayformula to autofill column based on a condition.
=IFERROR(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((Research!$B$1:$B$100)="Yes",REGEXEXTRACT(Research!$A$1:$A$100,".*"),)),"WHERE Col1 is not null")).

It does what it's supposed to, but the problem comes if that condition changes at any point (so it's not true anymore) the value in the cell filled with the array will get deleted but will also offset all the other rows after it (same happens if I insert new row with 'Yes' value in between other rows, in my Research sheet from where I extract my data from).
Is there any way if I need to make changes to the condition in the sheet from where I extract data > and not offset everything else in the sheet where I use the array formula? (either delete the entire row if the value doesn't meet the condition anymore, or insert new row if it meets the condition (not just replace the value in previous cell in its spot, cuz then all the other fields are mismatched). I'm a beginner with excel, I hope that makes sense. [Sheet ex](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v-ZVfWuFWvYK5JPXMqoe0x-21djeS9mFRodnp1QSABU/edit#gid=0)

- [Condition in Main Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmDGe.png) > [Result in Array sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhQkT.png)
  (these are the ok examples)
- [Changed value to yes for Agency 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJHc9.png) > [Inserted in Agency's 5 place > and offsets everything after it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3wH6.png)

Comment: Should I change the title or any other suggestions on what is not clear?

Comment: Would you share a link with edit permission to a **sample** file, so we can test it?

Comment: @DavidLeal I added the edit permission to the Sheet ex already linked, and locked the given examples

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the spreadsheet for my examples.

Method A: Separate the sheets of input and output

Method B: Input on Research and output on Initiative

Method C: Use Google Apps Script to 'avoid' offset upon change of `Take?` value. (example is not provided)

Comment: That works nice, but it was not really what I was looking for as I have many other fields that would need to be filled in, in their respective sheet and need to keep it neat. Thank you though!